# Test if line segments are part of a triangle

Tags: computational-geometry

This looks simple, but I can't figure it out. I want an algorithm that will determine if three line segments are part of a triangle.

- If the line segments form a triangle the answer should be `True`.
- If one can get a triangle by extending one or more line segment, the
  answer should be `True`.
- If some portion of one or more line segment would not be part of the triangle, the answer should be `False`.

The line segments in my first example are part of a triangle:

```
lines1 = Line[{{{3.4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {4.2, 5}}}];
Graphics[lines1, ImageSize -> {150, 150}]
```

[image: example 1]

The lines in the next two examples are not part of a triangle:

```
lines2 = Line[{{{0, 0.8}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {8, 3}}}];
Graphics[lines2, ImageSize -> {150, 150}]
```

[image: example 2]

```
lines3 = Line[{{{3.4, 2}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {6, -3}}}];
Graphics[lines3, ImageSize -> {150, 150}]
```

[image: example 3]

Comment: Your examples 2 and 3 are not clear: according to your rule "If can get a triangle by extending one or more line segment, the answer should be True" they are part of triangle.

Comment: It is sufficient to check if none of 2 vectors out of 3 along the segments are collinear.

Comment: In examples 2, 3 line segments could be extended to make a triangle, but in each of those examples would violate the third bullet that I specify. Part of at least one line segment would not be part of the triangle. It is not enough to perform a collinear check.

Comment: Thanks for making these clarifications. Can line segments be disconnected, or are you only considering 2D objects that are specified by 4 (or less) distinct points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an [angle calculation function (`anglecalc`)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171979/363) to measure the angle between two vectors.  With `closedQ` to check whether the lines will converge to a triangle.

```
anglecalc[u_, v_] := Mod[(ArcTan @@ v) - (ArcTan @@ u), 2 Pi]

closedQ[lines_] := Module[{a, b, c, d, e, f},
  {{c, d}, {e, f}} = #1 - #2 & @@@ Partition[lines, 2, 1];
  {a, b} = anglecalc[##] 180/Pi & @@@ {{-d, c}, {-f, e}};
  a + b < 180 || a + b > 540]
```

Mapping `closedQ` over the OP's lines.

```
lines1 = {{{3.4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {4.2, 5}}};
lines2 = {{{0, 0.8}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {8, 3}}};
lines3 = {{{3.4, 2}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {6, -3}}};

closedQ /@ {lines1, lines2, lines3}
```

> ```
> {True, False, False}
> ```

***How it works***

`anglecalc` finds the clockwise angle from `v` to `u`.

```
x = lines3[[{1, 2}]]
Graphics[Line[x], ImageSize -> 150]
{u, v} = lines3[[1]] - lines3[[2]]
anglecalc[u, v] 180/Pi
```

[image]

```
{u, v}
```

> ```
> {{0.4, 2}, {-2, -0.2}}
> ```

Comment: This method does not check if any line segment would not be part of the triangle, e.g. `test6 = {{{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {1, 
    2}}}; isclosed = 
 closedQ[test6]; Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.2], Arrow[test6], 
  Text[isclosed, Center]}]`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fast and simple solution.

The infinite lines extending any given line segments will always create a triangle on a plane as long as they are not parallel. Therefore, what you want is that all of the given line segments should belong to that triangle.

An easy way to check this is to consider the region **ball** which encloses that triangle, and then use the command *RegionWithin* to check if the given line segments belong to that ball. If all of them belong to that ball, then the answer to your question is True.

Following command basically does that:

```
ClearAll[test];
test = Module[{lines, points, disk, lineSegments},
lines[i_] := (InfiniteLine /@ #)[[i]];
points = 
 Flatten[Table[{x, y} /. 
    Flatten[Solve[{x, y} \[Element] lines[i] && {x, y} \[Element] 
        lines[j], {x, y}]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, i + 1, 3}], 1];
disk = BoundingRegion[points, "MinDisk"];
lineSegments = 
 Flatten@Table[Line[{#[[i]], #[[j]]}], {i, 1, 2}, {j, i + 1, 3}];
Graphics[Flatten@Join[{disk}, {Red}, lineSegments]]
And @@ Table[RegionWithin[disk, lineSegments[[i]]], {i, 3}]
] &;
```

The scooping variable *lines* are the infinite lines to which given line segments belong to. The variable *points* are the intersection points with which we create the variable *disk*. Finally, we generate the line segments with the variable *lineSegments* and check if they belong to the region of *ball*.

The good thing about this method is that it also visualizes how the situation is True or False. For example, for the examples you gave, we immediately see that for

```
lines1 = {{{3.4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {4.2, 5}}};
lines2 = {{{0, 0.8}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {8, 3}}};
lines3 = {{{3.4, 2}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {5, 0.2}}, {{5, 0.2}, {6, -3}}};
```

we get 
[image: region check example 1]

Of course there is nothing special about the lines being connected to each other, which is the case in your examples. We see that the code works equally well for disconnected line segments, for example:

```
test4 = {{{1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}};
test5 = {{{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}};
test6 = {{{1, 5}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}};
```

[image: region check example 2]

Answer (score 2):

`lines1` is part of a triangle if and only if `P[[2, 1]] == P[[1, 2]]` and
`P[[2,2]] == P[[3, 1]]` are fulfilled and if the following linear equation in the two variables `s` and `t` has a solution with `t>=0` and `s>=0`:

```
 P = N@lines1[[1]];
 Solve[P[[1, 2]] + s (P[[1, 1]] - P[[1, 2]]) == P[[3, 1]] + t (P[[3, 2]] - P[[3, 1]]), {s, t}]
```

The following function checks for all of this:

```
triangleQ[line_Line] := With[{P = N@line[[1]]},
  If[Length[P] == 3,
   If[P[[1, 2]] == P[[2, 1]] && P[[2, 2]] == P[[3, 1]],
    With[{
      A = Transpose[{(P[[1, 1]] - P[[1, 2]]), -(P[[3, 2]] - P[[3, 1]])}],
      b = P[[2, 2]] - P[[2, 1]]
      },
     If[Abs[Det[A]] > Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon],
      And @@ Thread[LinearSolve[A, b] >= 0.],
      False
      ]
     ],
    False
    ],
   False
   ]
  ]
```

Of course, this function can be optimized, for example, by solving the linear 2 x 2 system symbolically and by applying `Compile`.

Comment: Similarly to my answer, yours does not check for line segments outside the triangle.  E.g. `test6 = Line[{{{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {1, 
     2}}}]; istriangle = 
 triangleQ[test6]; Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.2], Arrow[test6[[1]]], 
  Text[istriangle, Center]}]`