# Better way to calculate angle between lines?

Tags: computational-geometry

I wrote `anglecalc` to calculate the clockwise angle from line `a` to `b`.  Initially I thought `VectorAngle` would do it, but I had to add extra functionality.  Is there a simpler way?

```
rotationangle[{i_, j_}] := Which[
  i >= 0 && j >= 0, VectorAngle[{1, 0}, {i, j}],
  i < 0 && j >= 0, VectorAngle[{0, 1}, {i, j}] + Pi/2,
  i < 0 && j < 0, VectorAngle[{-1, 0}, {i, j}] + Pi,
  i >= 0 && j < 0, VectorAngle[{0, -1}, {i, j}] + 3 Pi/2]

quadrant[{i_, j_}] := Which[
  i >= 0 && j >= 0, 1, i < 0 && j >= 0, 2,
  i < 0 && j < 0, 3, i >= 0 && j < 0, 4]

anglecalc[u_, v_] := Module[{a, theta, r},
  a = VectorAngle[u, v];
  theta = -rotationangle[u];
  r = RotationTransform[theta];
  If[quadrant[r[v]] > 2, 2 Pi - a, a]]
```

[image]

Test cases

```
r = RotationTransform[90 Degree];

(* case 1 *)
{a, b} = {{{4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {10, 1}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 2 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.22], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 3 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 4 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.22], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 5 *)
{a, b} = {{{4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {10, -7}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.12], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {120, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 6 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.09], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 120}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 7 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.12], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {120, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 8 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.09], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 120}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 9 *)
{a, b} = {{{4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {-7, -5}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 10 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.13], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 11 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 12 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.13], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 13 *)
{a, b} = {{{4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {-7, 5}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 14 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.21], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 15 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]

(* case 16 *)
{a, b} = r /@ {a, b};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.21], Arrow[{a, b}]}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150}]
{u, v} = a - b;
N[anglecalc[v, -u] 180/Pi]
```

Comment: First thought occurs to me is to use dot and cross product of 3D vectors.

Comment: You want to find the angle by which `a` is to be turned clockwise in order to point in the opposite direction of `b`?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP My code developed a bit accidentally.  The arrows are just to show the `Line` order, not the vectors.  I reversed the direction of one vector in the function call, e.g. `anglecalc[v, -u]`.

Comment: Might I ask if you're looking for something particularly special in an answer (since you haven't accepted one yet)?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Heh, yes I've found it difficult to choose between your answer and chyanog's because the latter actually shows how `VectorAngle` can be applied.

Comment: I understand, I found his answer quite clever too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This passed all test cases, I think:

```
anglecalc[vec1_, vec2_] := Mod[(ArcTan @@ vec2) - (ArcTan @@ vec1), 2 π]
```

Comment: Some amazing answers here.

Answer (score 15):

For a start, you can use this signed-angle function, which involves the two-argument version of `ArcTan`:

```
myVectorAngle[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := Evaluate[
  With[{code = ReIm[(y1 + I y2)/(x1 + I x2)] // ComplexExpand // Simplify},
   ArcTan @@ code]
  ]
```

Some usage example:

```
{a, b} = {{{4, 3}, {3, 0}}, {{3, 0}, {10, 1}}} // N;
Pi - myVectorAngle @@ (a - b)
```

> 1.10715

If you have to use that a lot, you may switch to the following compiled function:

```
cf = Block[{P, PP},
   PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j, k], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}];
   With[{code = 
      N[Pi] - myVectorAngle[PP[[1, 1]] - PP[[1, 2]], PP[[2, 1]] - PP[[2, 2]]]},
    Compile[{{P, _Real, 3}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];

cf[{a, b}]
```

> 1.10715

Answer (score 10):

```
kek[x_] := 2 \[Pi] - If[x > 0, x, 2 \[Pi] + x]
anglecalc2[u_, v_] := kek[(ToPolarCoordinates[RotationMatrix[{v, {1, 0}}].(u)][[2]])]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Clear["`*"];
vecs = Join[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^4, 2, 2}], {{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, -1}}}];

anglecalc1[u_, v_] := Mod[ArcTan[Dot[u, v], Det[{u, v}]], 2 Pi];
anglecalc2[u_, v_] := Mod[(2 UnitStep[Det[{u, v}]] - 1) VectorAngle[u, v], 2 Pi];

(* LLlAMnYP's method *)
anglecalc3[u_, v_] := Mod[(ArcTan @@ v) - (ArcTan @@ u), 2 Pi]

r1 = anglecalc1 @@@ vecs;
r2 = anglecalc2 @@@ vecs;
r3 = anglecalc3 @@@ vecs;

r1 - r2 // MinMax
r2 - r3 // MinMax
```

Output:

> {-8.88178*10^-16, 8.88178*10^-16}
> {-1.77636*10^-15, 1.33227*10^-15}

**Original answer**

```
anglecalc[u_, v_] := Mod[ArcTan[Dot[u, v], Det[{u, v}]], 2π]
```

or

```
anglecalc[u_, v_] := Mod[Sign[Det[{u, v}]] VectorAngle[u, v], 2π]
```

Comment: Really interesting to see an answer making use of `VectorAngle`, but the answer to this should be Pi, not zero: `u = {0, -1}; v = {0, 1}; Mod[Sign[Det[{u, v}]] VectorAngle[u, v], 2 Pi]`