# (vector)Rotation for A to point towards B

Tags: vector

Assuming,
Point A=vector2( 210,400)
B=vector2(-120,480)

Is there a short formula to find the angle to rotate A towards B ?
(A is currently heading towards the Y-axis)

Currently, using Pythagorean theorem by getting quadrant info for third point (A.x,B.y) or (B.x,A.y). Then acos... Little complicated.

> Respecting A if if B.x>A.x then quadrant=1. Assuming C=(A.x,B.y)
> Rotation=acos(AC/BC)

Comment: [`VectorAngle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorAngle.html)?

Comment: Are you intereseted in a formula, say for mathematical interest, or are you trying to solve for the actual angle? VectorAngle is the easiest way to get the latter. In your specific case, `VectorAngle[vecA, vecB]` will do the trick (where `vecA={210,400}` and `vecB={-120,480}`. Apply `N` to get a finite precision value.

Comment: @lericr  VectorAngle[vecA, vecB]? Is it a function we can call in lua or python?

Comment: Possible duplicate [better-way-to-calculate-angle-between-lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171968/better-way-to-calculate-angle-between-lines)

Answer (score 2):

`VectorAngle` returns the same value for rotating $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{b}$ as it does for rotating $\vec{b}$ to $\vec{a}$.  If you want a formula for the *signed* angle, try this

```
Clear[angle]
angle[v1_, v2_] := Arg[Complex @@ v2] - Arg[Complex @@ v1]
```

Example usage:

```
{a, b} = {{210, 400}, {-120, 480}};

angle[a, b]/Degree // N   (* 41.735716276 *)

angle[b, a]/Degree // N   (* -41.735716276 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative- Real-version(2D)

```
ArcTan[a . b, Det[{a, b}]]/Degree//N (* 41.7357*)
ArcTan[b . a, Det[{b, a}]]/Degree//N (* -41.7357*)
```

or  `ArcTan[a . b, Cross[ a]. b ]/Degree`